# Is it possible to model a microwave resonator in SPICE

Tags: spice, microwave, resonance

I just wanted to know if it was possible to model a microwave resonator in spice software or somehow import it from somewhere to spice to carry out analysis. 
Also if it is not possible to model the microwave resonator in spice, will using a series or parallel resonance circuit be able to 'replace' the microwave resonator/cavity.
I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can properly describe the resonator, you should be able to simulate it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. However I am unsure as to what you mean when you say properly describe the resonator, because the microwave resonator is just a microwave cavity used in labs. Do you mean model the resonator as an LC circuit ?

Comment: In a word, "Yes". Be sure you account for Q, though,  by accounting for the losses in the cavity.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  The thing is I want to study the changes in Q factor of the microwave cavity, by changing the coupling. So will it be a problem that I will be modelling the actually cavity as a simple LC circuit and accounting for the Q as the Q is one of the main things I have to look at ?

Comment: If you don't account for the losses,  then how can you assume that your simulator will?

Comment: I thought that the simulator , which is the LC circuit model of the microwave cavity in SPICE will not account for any losses as that would be an ideal world scenario?.                                                    Thus when I calculate the Q i will have to essentially deduct the losses ?.

Comment: As I understand it, that's correct.